# C++ compiler support to detect returning a reference to a temporary object

Tags: c++, reference, g++, clang++, temporary-objects

There is a snipped code, that returns a reference to a temporary object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string& forward(const std::string& s)
{
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string& hello = forward("this is a random string with a reference to a temporary object");
    std::cout << hello << "\n";
}
```

I compiled the snipped as following:

`g++ -std=c++20 -Wpedantic -Wall test.cpp -o test`

`clang++ -std=c++20 -Wpedantic -Wall test.cpp -o test`

and I expected a warning message `warning: returning reference to temporary`, but there was no warning about this bugged use of the "forward()" function.

Does any C++ compiler support detection of such cases when returning temporary objects?

Comment: `forward` can accept rvalues and lvalues.  The compiler would have to do a complete trace of the call to workout what is passed in every call. If you change `forward` to `const std::string& forward(const std::string && s)` do you get an error ?

Comment: gcc will [produce the warning](https://godbolt.org/z/nvada5G1M) you are looking for at `-O -Wall`

Comment: I tried with `const std::string && s` and with `-O -Wall`, and the result is the same - no warnings/errors.

g++ version: 11.3.0

Comment: 11.3 is silent, apparently introduced in gcc 12.x

Comment: Also if you use the result of `forward` in the same expression as the call there is no problem as the lifetime of the temporary will still be ok. eg `const std::string& hello = forward("qewr") + "something";` is ok.  This creates a new temporary string (from the addition) and then lifetime extends it.

Comment: `forward` is only a potential problem if it is called with a temporary parameter. On it's own there is no reason for any warning.

Comment: @JaMiT you're right, the function itself is not, but this particular use case is. I compiled the `std::max` snippet from the cpp notes for curiosity, and GCC12 doesn't produce any warning or error (ASAN or analyzers can catch it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with the function itself or the call to it. When `forward` returns the temporary object is still alive. Its lifetime only ends *after* the initialization of `hello`. Therefore a warning saying that the function returns a dangling reference wouldn't be correct. The result of the function call can still be used in the same full-expression without anything dangling.

You only have a problem after the initialization of `hello` when `hello` immediately becomes dangling. And then the use in `std::cout << hello << "\n";` has UB.

To recognize that the initialization of `hello` causes access to a dangling pointer later in the output statement, the compiler needs to inline at least `forward`. So it wouldn't be surprising if the compiler's analysis can only detect this issue with optimizations enabled.

That seems to be exactly the case here for GCC 12 and later, which provides the warning with optimizations enabled (at least `-O1`) and `-Wall`. Clang and MSVC don't seem to perform such an analysis at the moment.

I would however expect static analyzers like clang-analyze as well as runtime sanitizers like ASAN (`-fsanitize=address` for GCC/Clang) to detect this issue (and ASAN does for both GCC and Clang at any optimization level in my tests).

Comment: ASAN works for both GCC (11.3.0) and Clang (14.0.0), but it looks like only GCC12 can detect this problem without any analyzers/sanitizers (as @teapot418 mentioned).